# ERROR READING SESSION DATA in Kohana 3.2

Tags: php, session, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

I am having a problem with the session with the web development framework Kohana 3.2 that apparently is a bug that, at most, can be workarounded. It reports SESSION_EXCEPTION [ 1 ]: ERROR READING SESSION DATA.
My Kohana application isn't in the root folder and I wonder if that has something to do with it.

I have tryed several possible solutions but none of them have worked. Here are some of them:

**1)** using one library (Facebook SDK), session was initialized on it's own, and session handling was done using the $_SESSION variable. So there were two cookies - session (Kohanas session id) and PHPSESSID. ***=> There is only one "session" and "PHPSESSID" variables in $_COOKIE***

**2)** Workaround or solution was setting in php.ini session.auto_start = 0. ***=> I am working in a shared server (iPage) and I am pretty sure I can't edit the php.ini file.***

**3)** some user's session files were trying to get saved to a directory that didn't exist. So he changed the session.save_path to a valid path and that fixed it. ***=> [If he was talking about this php native function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) , I've created a directory and set it calling this function as the session folder. It didn't work as well. However, I got unsure if I did it correctly (the path "/" would be the root, and not where kohana is in, right?)***

4) Apparently this bug is reported to kohana [here](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/3844) but I wasn't able to act from reading it.

Is somebody out there able to help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the piece of code that throws this error and explain what you are doing and trying to achieve?

Comment: I just had this issue, with me the problem was trying to connect to a database that did not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching very much about it and upgradion to KOHANA 3.3, I came to the conclusion that this error was caused when the native function session_start() was called in the Kohana_Session_Native class. It was caused because PHP was **trying to save the session in an unavaiable directory**. Thus, i just changed this path in php.ini and everything was solved. You  may also just call the **function session_save_path('YOUR_PATH')** in the application/bootstrap.php.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i run "chmod 777 -R /path/to/session" command and the error has disappeared.