# Kohana error reading session data

Tags: php, session, kohana

I have an application working ok in localhost and in a testing server. Now I'm passing it to another server, and I get the error 'Error reading session data'. I checked php.ini configuration and i can't find a difference with the localhost config.

I also checked `session.php`, auth.php and `bootstrap.php` from Kohana and doesn't find anything.

Edit: 
I checked other answers in other posts about this issue, but I checked php.ini session_save_path and it is commented in both localhost and the other server, so it takes the system default temp folder.
I checked other configs in php.ini without luck...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR READING SESSION DATA in Kohana 3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810509/error-reading-session-data-in-kohana-3-2)

Comment: Is this error consistent or app is throwing this error randomly.

Comment: It is a consistent error...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough data about error. The fastest way is small dirty hack:

find in `system / classes / Kohana / Session.php` line `throw new Session_Exception('Error reading session data` (method `read()`) and change to:

```
throw new Session_Exception('Error reading session data.'. " [SID:".$id."(".$this->id()."), name:".$this->_name."][Details: " . $e . "]\n", NULL, Session_Exception::SESSION_CORRUPT);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped!